# How to concat the array of columns in laravel raw query method?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have the array of columns and wanna use it in mysql CONCAT through laravel raw query. How to add pass these array of columns(able to convert it to string)
the array

```
> array:5 [▼   0 => "title"   1 => "featured"   2 => "content"   3 =>
> "category_id"   4 => "slug" ]
```

expected output:

> `('title','featured','content','category_id','slug')`

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

In php arrays are indexed by int by default (thus, your var_dump will always shows your array with these indexes). If by the output you mean that you'd like to convert your array to a String you can do it like so:

```
$arrayStr = "(".join(',', $yourArray).")";
```

Regards

Answer (score 1):

You can approach this as

```
$data = [
  0 => 'title',
  1 => 'featured',
  2 => 'content',
  3 => 'category_id',
  4 => 'slug'
];
$columns = "'".implode("','",$data)."'";
$res = Component::select(DB::raw("CONCAT($columns) AS Alias"))->get();
```